# How can I transform Kibana data into graphic in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

I have this data stored in ElasticSearch :

```
{
    "_index": ".kibana",
    "_type": "visualization",
    "_id": "bar-teste",
    "_version": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "title": "bar teste",
        "visState": "{\"title\":\"New Visualization\",\"type\":\"histogram\",\"params\":{\"shareYAxis\":true,\"addTooltip\":true,\"addLegend\":true,\"scale\":\"linear\",\"mode\":\"stacked\",\"times\":[],\"addTimeMarker\":false,\"defaultYExtents\":false,\"setYExtents\":false,\"yAxis\":{}},\"aggs\":[{\"id\":\"1\",\"type\":\"cardinality\",\"schema\":\"metric\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"entityFk\"}},{\"id\":\"2\",\"type\":\"terms\",\"schema\":\"segment\",\"params\":{\"field\":\"entityObj.description\",\"size\":3,\"order\":\"asc\",\"orderBy\":\"1\"}}],\"listeners\":{}}",
        "uiStateJSON": "{}",
        "description": "",
        "version": 1,
        "kibanaSavedObjectMeta": {
            "searchSourceJSON": "{\"index\":\"index*\",\"query\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"*\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}},\"filter\":[]}"
        }
    }
}
```

This data is a Vertical Bar Chart. I can get this data by an HTTP request.
The Question is : it's possible tranform this data into a graphic in Java?
Thanks.